# Gujrati font store in sql server with C# Window app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Here i set font type for text box is **Gujarati** Saral-1 in **C# win app** for offline and when i enter the text it display Gujarati font,

but when i set back-end side i.e. C# it again display in English font.

plz tell me how to get **Gujarati font** in back-end c# from text box

so finally i store that data in sq l server

Answer (score 0):

in user sql query pass string value with N prefix like

```
 INSERT INTO [tblLH_PhrasePhp]([SourceLanguageID],[VideoID],[SourcePhrase],[TargetPhrase],[Phonetics]) VALUES(2, @VideoId, N'Hello', N'你好', N'Nǐ hǎo')
```

Comment: according to your code it shows error i.e. **; expected**